# How to use select binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an array of objects in javascript. The array is :

```
    [
     { "Name": "A", "Id": "1" , "FID": "1" },
     { "Name": "B", "Id": "2" , "FID": "1" },
     { "Name": "C", "Id": "3" , "FID": "1" },
     { "Name": "D", "Id": "4" , "FID": "1" },
     { "Name": "E", "Id": "5" , "FID": "1" },
    ]
```

I am using knockout.js. I want to use select binding to bind this array with select list. So that the select list contains the Name property value of this array in its drop-down. How can i do this ?

Comment: ohh yes, but it is a typo, sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
<select data-bind='options:Your_Observable_Array, optionsText:"Name", optionsValue:"Id"'>
```